# Can I call the SparkContext constructor twice?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I need to do something like the following.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val master = new SparkContext(conf).master

if (master == "local[*]") // running locally
{
  conf.set(...)
  conf.set(...)
}
else // running on a cluster
{
  conf.set(...)
  conf.set(...)
}

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I first check whether I am running in local mode or cluster mode, and set the conf properties accordingly. But just to know about the master, I first have to create a SparkContext object. And after setting the conf properties, I obviously create another SparkContext object. Is this fine? Or Spark would just ignore my second constructor? If that is the case, in what other way I can find about the master (whether local or in cluster mode that is) before creating the SparkContext object?

Comment: You can pass your configurations with spark submit command as well. `spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=6123`

Comment: And what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I misread your question for setting conf parameters depending on the master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting multiple contexts at the same time will give an error.

You can get around this by stopping the first context before creating the second.

```
master.stop()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

It's silly to do this though, you can get the master from  the spark conf without needing to start a spark context.

```
conf.get("spark.master")
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I asked as well, that can you get spark.master with conf only. Thanks for the answer!